# Could not find module with name '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel'

Tags: electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

electron-forge make

✔ Checking your system
✔ Loading configuration
✖ Resolving make targets
› Could not find module with name '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel'. If this is a package from NPM, make sure it's listed in the devDependencies of your package.json. If this is a local module, make sure you have the correct path to its entry point. Try u…
◼ Running package command
◼ Running preMake hook
◼ Making distributables
◼ Running postMake hook

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: Could not find module with name '@electron-forge/maker-squirrel'. If this is a package from NPM, make sure it's listed in the devDependencies of your package.json. If this is a local module, make sure you have the correct path to its entry point. Try using the DEBUG="electron-forge:require-search" environment variable for more information.
at Task.task (D:\ExtractCode\filesend\node_modules@electron-forge\core\dist\api\make.js:102:35)
at Task.run (D:\ExtractCode\filesend\node_modules\listr2\dist\index.cjs:978:35)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iVKy.png)

I've tried many times, but I keep encountering the same error. To address it, I'm using @electron-forge/maker-squirrel version 6.4.2. After that, I run npx electron-forge import, followed by npm run make. Additionally, I'm using beta versions 6.0.0-beta.53, 6.0.0-beta.49, 6.0.0-beta.50, and 6.0.0-beta.51.